# Integrating the phase space probability density function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, phase-space

If we consider a thermodyn. system a gas made out of N classical non interacting particles, with fixed energy. The appropriate ensemble to associate to this system is the Microcanonical ensemble. I know that the phase space pdf ($\rho$) in this case is constant over some region, which contains all the microstates that satisfy the condition (of the energy fixed and at a certain value) and zero elsewhere. At the same time, an integration over this region should give us 1. So I am trying to prove the last part.
$\vec x= (\vec q_1,...\vec q_N,\vec p_1,...\vec p_N)$

$\Omega(E)=\int \theta(E-H(\vec x))d\vec x$. In phase space this is the volume of the 6N dim. hypersphere. It can also be interpreted as the nr. of microstates with energy equal or smaller than $E$.

$\Sigma(E)=\frac{d\Omega}{dE}=\int\delta(E-H(\vec x))d\vec x$. This is  the surface of the 6N dim. hypersphere. It can also be interpreted as the nr. of microstates whose energy is exactly $E$.

$\Sigma(E)dE=d\Omega$ is the nr. of states with energy within an interval centered at $E$.

For the MCS:

$\rho^{eq(\vec x)}=\frac{1}{\Sigma(E)dE} $ for $E\le H(\vec x)\le E+dE$

or

$\rho^{eq(\vec x)}=0$ in every other case.

Now I want to perform the following integration:

$\int \rho (d???)=1$

I am integrating over what and which boundaries? I can integrate over $d\vec x$ but I believe I can also integrate over $dE$.

I did the following:

$$\int_{E}^{E+dE}\rho dE=\int_{E}^{E+dE}\frac{1}{\Sigma E}=\int_{E}^{E+dE}\frac{dE}{d\Omega}=\frac{E}{d\Omega}=1$$. I don't think it's right.

Comment: Well, $\rho$ is a function of what...? You also have it in your title.

Comment: $\rho$ is constant for once, and also is 1/nr. of microstates that have energy within an interval centered around E, which E, is the energy of the macro state of the system. Other then this, I don't know what you mean with $\rho$ being a function of what

Comment: $\rho$ is not constant.

Comment: The Wikipedia article implies that it's constant within the region of integration and zero elsewhere : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcanonical_ensemble#:~:text=In%20simple%20terms,range%20of%20energy%2C

Comment: Indeed: It is not constant. Sorry, I don't get the question here. Which book do you follow? What does it say?! Have you checked *any* other source?

Comment: I have and what I wrote, it's letter of letter what the professor in our lecture wrote. This is known as the fundamental postulate of thermodynamics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's worth taking a moment to clarify some things. The phase space probability density $\rho:X\rightarrow \mathbb R$ (where $X$ is the phase space, typically something like $\mathbb R^{6N}$) is defined such that the probability that the system occupies some region $R\subseteq X$ of phase space is given by $\int_R \rho(\mathbf x)\ \mathrm d^{6N}x$.

Now, when we talk about the **microcanonical** ensemble, we run into a problem - namely, that the system is constrained to be on a surface of constant energy. The problem is that such a surface has zero volume, just as the surface of a sphere has zero volume in 3D space (more specifically, it is a set of measure zero). As a result, in the language of measure theory $\rho$ is zero *almost everywhere* and so it cannot assign probabilities in the way mentioned above.

There are essentially two ways to handle this.  The first way is not to ask for a probability density $\rho$ on $X$, but rather a probability density $\tilde \rho$ on the surface $\mathscr S_E$ of constant energy $E$.  If $\mathscr S_E$ has surface area $\Sigma(E)$, then the fundamental postulate of statistical mechanics tells us that $\tilde \rho (\mathbf x) = 1/\Sigma(E)$, which yields $1$ when integrated over all of $\mathscr S_E$. Note that formally $\rho(\mathbf x) = \tilde \rho(\mathbf x) \ \delta(H(\mathbf x)-E)$, and so this approach is equivalent to allowing $\rho$ to have a delta function in it.

---

The *alternative* approach is to define a small energy width $\Delta\ll E$ and allow $\rho$ to be non-zero inside the shell of width $\Delta$ around $\mathscr S_E$. This has the substantial benefit of not needing to deal with any delta functions or sets of measure zero, but on the other hand we must always bear in mind that $\Delta$ is meant to be vanishingly small (though more often than not, it quickly drops out from any calculations).

In this case, if $\Sigma(E)$ is the surface area of $\mathscr S_E$ as before, then $\Sigma(E)\Delta$ is (approximately) the volume of the shell in question. The phase space probability density then becomes

$$\rho(\mathbf x) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{\Sigma(E)\Delta}& |H(\mathbf x)-E|<\Delta/2 \\ 0 & \text{else} \end{cases}$$

When integrated over all of phase space, only the region inside the shell contributes and so once again the integral yields $1$ as expected.

> I am integrating over what and which boundaries? I can integrate over $\mathrm d\vec x$ but I believe I can also integrate over $\mathrm dE$.

Whether you take the first or second approach outlined above (it seems your instructor does the latter), the integral is taken over (a subset of) the phase space. It is not taken over $E$.  Under certain circumstances, it can be *converted* to an integral over $E$ via a change of variables (this is true for e.g. an ideal gas).

Comment: J.Murray, thank you for the precise answer. The last part is what I want. As you can see in my post, I utilze the expression for $\rho$ when it's non zero and I integrate over the region where $\rho $ is non-zero in phase space, which is the hyper spherical shell. Ofc you can even integrate over the entire phase space, but only the mentioned region plays a role. My aim with this post, was the derivation that the integral is equal to one, when considering the expression $\rho=\frac{1}{\Sigma E\Delta}$

Comment: @imbAF I see. It is equal to 1 in the sense that $\Sigma(E)\Delta$ is the volume of the phase space on which $\rho$ is nonzero, so $\int \rho \mathrm d\vec x = \Sigma(E)\Delta / \Sigma(E)\Delta = 1$. This of course relies on the approximation that $\Delta$ is sufficiently small that $\Sigma(E)\Delta$ is a good approximation for the volume of the shell.

Comment: So we do integrate over $d\vec x$. I thought since $\rho$ was expressed as a function of $E$, we could have do it over the energy

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful. If I understand correctly, your system has the Hamiltonian (normalising mass):
$$
H = \sum_i\frac{p_i^2}{2}
$$
so the support of your ensemble is actually a cylinder i.e. isomorphic to $\mathbb S^{dN-1}\times\mathbb R^{dN}$, a hyper-surface in the phase space isomorphic to $\mathbb R^{dN}$ ($d$ dimension, $N$ number of particles).

If you wanted the true hypersphere $\mathbb S^{2dN-1}$, then you would rather need to consider $N$ independent harmonic oscillators of Hamiltonian (normalised frequency):
$$
H = \sum_i\frac{p_i^2}{2}+\frac{q_i^2}{2}
$$

For the question mark measure, the natural measure to use is given by $d^{dN}qd^{dN}p = d^{2dN}x$ (the usual Lebesgue measure). It is invariant by change of canonical variables (in particular by conservative flow) and can be constructed geometrically from the symplectic structure of phase space.

The momentum integration is well defined, since it's the hyper surface of a sphere. However, the space integration is infinite when the domain is unbounded. This is why you typically focus on a box/periodic boundary conditions to get a finite volume $V$, and hope that the quantity you are interested does not depend on edge effects.

You can directly calculate $\Omega$ using:
$$
\Omega = \int d^{2dN}x \delta(E-H)
$$
If you are unfamiliar with integrations involving Dirac deltas, it is easier to rather calculate:
$$
\omega = \int d^{2dN}x \theta(E-H)
$$
with $\theta$ the Heaviside function and realise that:
$$
\Omega = \frac{d\omega}{dE}
$$

In your case, you get (volume of a $dN$ dimensional ball, which can be done using the usual gaussian trick):

$$
\omega = V^N\frac{\pi^{N/2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{dN+1}{2}\right)}(2E)^{dN/2}
$$
so you get:
$$
\Omega = V^N\frac{\pi^{N/2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{dN}{2}\right)}(2E)^{dN/2-1}
$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: As far as I understand (probably I don't) the question, then this (correct) answer does not help here. OP want's to know, I suppose, why their last line is correct/wrong or anything (?).

Comment: Well, I think that the issue was which measure to use (question marks) and there was an initial mistake in the domain of integration. I also added an edit to tie in with the "cumulative" potential as well which is what I think was being hinted in the final lines.

Comment: Okay... I mean, I really don't understand the question. You're right, the question marks indicate that they ask which measure to use; OTOH, they explicitly state " I can integrate over dx⃗  but I believe I can also integrate over dE." and then some calculations follow. Anyway, +1, maybe it helps OP to settle their confusion.

Comment: Thanks, anyway I'm expecting the question to be modified. I agree with you that the question is not very clear. I'm merely presenting a similar, viable method to solve the underlying problem.